# Netbeans 8.2 folders not showing (folders created by php for image storage)

Tags: php, netbeans-8

Using Netbeans 8.2 with php code, windows 10 Xampp local system.  The php code creates several folders to store images as user blogs are created.  Most of the image folders show up as they are created, but a few do not.  I can see them in the Windows file explorer, but they do not show up in Netbeans.  Also, a few of the folders show as empty folders, but I can also see in Windows file explorer that there are image files there.

Using Netbeans "projects" view vs "Files" view does not make a difference.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Just shut down and restarted Netbeans.  Seems to have solved the issue...